# Django prefetching nested tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following table structure:

```
menu --{ page --{ title
```

From the menu i would like to get fetch related pages. Pages also have related titles. 
The following code works exactly as i would like however the for loop generates an individual query each iteration.

The prefetch_related in the initial query doesn't seem to fetch the title. Is there a better way to do this resulting in a smaller number of queries?

```
 menu_data = MenuOrder.objects \
            .filter(menu__name=kwargs['menu']) \
            .filter(page__title_set__language=language) \
            .prefetch_related('page') \
            .order_by('priority')

    for menu_obj in menu_data:
        title_obj = menu_obj.page.title_set.get()
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found out that reversing the relationship has reduced the number of queries by a large number:

```
title_data = Title.objects \
    .filter(language=language) \
    .filter(page__menuorder__menu__name=kwargs['menu']) \
    .order_by('page__menuorder__priority')
```

I don't know if there is a better method, so for now i will accept this one. Thanks to everyone that took a look..

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

```
.prefetch_related('page__title')
```

[Quoting prefetch-related doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

The following are all legal:

```
Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related('pizzas__toppings')
```

Also, remember than for reduce queries you should use `select_related`

Comment: i did try the prefetch_relate, but a Relationship Manager is returned where i would a record would be.. so i have to run the .get() method on it to retrieve the db row resulting in the extra queries..